# Error while importing custom module within Django app

Tags: python, django, import, django-views

I have a django app within a django project in this structure :

```
my_project/
   my_app/
       migrations/
       static/
       template/
       admin.py
       apps.py
       views.py
       .
       .
       .
       my_module.py
```

My requirement is to import my_module within views.py. I have so far tried the following ways:

```
1.import my_module
2.from my_app import my_module
3.from . import my_module
```

> I start the server using  ./manage.py runserver

In all the above 3 cases I get the following error:

> Performing system checks...
>     usage: manage.py [-h] [-l LIST]
>     manage.py: error: unrecognized arguments: runserver

Any suggestions on how to import correctly would be of great help.

Comment: Since the error happens when you try and start the server, what does this have to do with importing a module?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Without the import, the server starts perfectly. I have, in fact been working on this since a couple of weeks.I ran into this just yesterday.

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: Its just  a one single line error that I get. I have edited the question with whatever traceback I got.

Comment: You seem to have somehow overwritten Django's manage.py with a completely different script. Django's one does not have -h or -l arguments.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue.The -h option does work for me, although -l does not.The file has not been edited or replaced either.Moreover, when the import statement is removed the manage.py works just fine.Anyway thanks for pointing out.I will try to reinstall django once more now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `__init__.py` in the directory to make python treats the directory as containing package.

Comment: I have tried this option too. Added a folder within my_app, with __init__.py in it and my_module files.I could import the directory but could not use the modules within